# How to use Reject file in infobright with version 4.0.6 GA

Tags: ice, infobright

In the [release notes of version 4.0.6 GA](http://www.infobright.org/downloads/ice/ICE_4.0.6_Release_Notes.pdf), we can found that the first new feature is "**Infobright Loader now supports a Reject file**"

But I cannot find anything more about this, just like how to use it, and in which case we may need it.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable the reject file functionality, you must specify BH_REJECT_FILE_PATH and one of
the associated parameters (BH_ABORT_ON_COUNT or BH_ABORT_ON_THRESHOLD).
For example, if you want to load data from the file DATAFILE.csv to table T but you expects
that 10 rows in this file might be wrongly formatted, you would run the following
commands:

set @BH_REJECT_FILE_PATH = '/tmp/reject_file';

set @BH_ABORT_ON_COUNT = 10;

load data infile DATAFILE.csv into table T;

If less than 10 rows are rejected, a warning will be output, the load will succeed and all
problematic rows will be output to the file /tmp/reject_file. If the Infobright Loader finds a
tenth bad row, the load will terminate with an error and all bad rows found so far will be
output to the file /tmp/reject_file.